# Groovy: Implicit call not working on instance variables inside closure

Tags: groovy, closures

A class implements `call` method so that it's objects can be called as a method. This works for most of the case but not when the call is being made inside a closure on a object which is instance variable of a class.

To demonstrate the problem, in the code below I've commented the interesting lines with numbers. While most variants result in same output, only the line with comment `5` doesn't work. It throws `groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Client2.instanceVar() is applicable for argument types: () values: []`)

Can someone help me understand the reason? Is it a bug?

```
class CallableObject {
    def call() { println "hello" }
}

class Client {
    def instanceVar = new CallableObject()

    def method() {
        def localVar = new CallableObject()
        def closure1 = { localVar() }
        def closure2 = { instanceVar.call() }
        def closure3 = { instanceVar() }     // doesn't work

        localVar()                           // 1
        instanceVar()                        // 2
        closure1()                           // 3
        closure2()                           // 4
        closure3()                           // 5
    }
}


new Client().method()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this will make it clear.

```
class CallableObject {
    def call() { println "hello" }
}

class Client {
    def instanceVar = new CallableObject()

    def getInstanceVar() {
        println "Getter Called"
        instanceVar 
    }

    def method() {
        def localVar = new CallableObject()
        def closure1 = { localVar() }
        def closure2 = { instanceVar.call() }
        def closure3 = { this.@instanceVar() } //should work now

        localVar()                           // 1
        instanceVar()                        // 2
        closure1()                           // 3
        closure2()                           // 4
        closure3()                         // 5
    }
}


new Client().method()
```

You will see "Getter Called" printed when `closure2()` invoked. For a global property to be accessed in the closure inside a method, the getter in called instead. To surmount the error you get, the field `instanceVar` needs to be accessed directly in order to implicitly use `call()`.

Comment: Although this would take the user of a DSL by surprise, I guess there is no other way :)